# Why is it so difficult to get this reputation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I had written an answer after much work and I almost see no sign of whether it's correct, though it shows my good amount of research, usually I see responses from mods and high ranking users in my answers. But here there's none, and there are no upvotes or even downvotes to tell me whether my answer is correct or wrong.

[Ionic radii of cations and anions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/179312/ionic-radii-of-cations-and-anions)

This might look like a silly question - in fact it is a very genuine question arisen from the user's confusion and misunderstanding of the book. And I have uploaded graphs and also researched the trend of what the user's confusion was.

Can anyone please let me know why users are so slow to respond (downvoting if my answer is wrong atleast)?

Comment: Uhm, you posted 15h ago. Participants on the site contribute their time freely. The response time on the site can vary as the answer by Karsten suggests. I suggest patience.

Comment: There are no votes on the original question. Does that mean that you don't find the question very good? Why did you then answer? If you found the question useful, what you answer might indicate, why did you not vote on it? If you're not voting on questions and answers, then others might do the same.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン, so that means I must increase my votes?

Comment: You might want to look at traffic. Here, traffic is not huge compared to math.SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chemistry is not a huge site, and depending on when you post, voters might be asleep. After a while, your post is no longer on the front page, and fewer people will see it.

In the case at hand, the OP was happy with the answer and accepted it. Over time, others might find the question and upvote the answer.